# debian: add user mysql to group www-data - how to take effect?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, credentials

i add the user mysql to the www-data in /etc/group,
is it really necessary to reboot to take effect?

Answer (score 1):

Any existing processes belonging to the mysql user may not recognize the group addition, and will need to be restarted.

Comment: Oh, sorry for excluding that I'm restarting mysql - no effect.

Comment: @user65297 are you stopping it completely or using service restart (which might just SIGHUP the process to make it pretend like you restarted it)?  If you've stopped it completely and started it again, then I'd say that your server is in the www-data group and something else (SELinux) is keeping it from doing whatever it is you're trying to get it to do.

Comment: What operation by the mysql user is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't do. How are you adding it - using `usermod` or editing the /etc/group file directly? `usermod` is the proper way to do this - I think editing the group file might lead to randomness.

Comment: trying out usermod -G www-data mysql gives expected result in /etc/group. Still no grant though..

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you do 'sudo -i -u mysql' (to get a login shell) and then issue 'groups'?

I echo justarobert, though: what is failing?  Telling us that is more likely to get you to a solution.